# Ubuntu and VHD grub rescue error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

this might be a bit complicated, but i hope someone can help me.

-I have my work PC, It has Ubuntu 14 installed and Windows 7
-I created a VHD image of the Windows partition from within Windows 7 OS
-The reason was to run that VHD on my windows 10 PC at home
-When i run it at home, it gives me the : GRUB RESCUE> prompt

I am not very technical, so can someone help ?
Is there a soultion, or should i have created the VHD in another way ?
Or is there an easy way to create the GRUB config files to point to auto start my Windows 7 in the VHD file ?

Makes any sense ?
thanks a lot
Sherif